# Laravel Query Fetch Wrong Data

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have written Laravel Search Query.

```
$product = Product::where('user_role_id', '=', 3)
                           ->where('user_id', '!=', $user_id)
                           ->where('quantity_in_stock', '>', 0);
                if (!empty($suggestion)) {
                    $product->where('product_name', 'like', '%' . $suggestion . '%')->orWhere('ndc_number', 'like', '%' . $suggestion . '%');
                }
                $search = $product->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
                $products = $search->toArray();
```

But my issue is that when I am looking search result I found such results which have `user_role_id => 2` But in query I have given equal to 3.

Can any help to sort out this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the query you have is translated to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE user_role_id = 1 
AND user_id != ? 
AND quantity_in_stick > 0 
AND product_name like %?% 
OR ndc_number like %?%
```

What I think you're trying to achieve is that the last two conditions are together, and as they are now, they affect the whole set of results as long as the OR statement is included. you want `(product_name like %?% or ndc_number like %?%)`

```
$product = Product::where('user_role_id', '=', 3)
                  ->where('user_id', '!=', $user_id)
                   ->where('quantity_in_stock', '>', 0);
if (!empty($suggestion)) {
    //You can re-assign the variable but I can't remember if you really need it or not, try it out 
    $product = $product->where(function($advancedWhere) use($suggestion) { 
        $advancedWhere->where('product_name', 'like', '%' . $suggestion . '%')
                      ->orWhere('ndc_number', 'like', '%' . $suggestion . '%');
    });
}
$search = $product->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
$products = $search->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks abr. it work. Just you need to give use($suggestion) too in your closure function. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assign to the variable after appending more where conditions like:

```
if (!empty($suggestion)) {
    $product = $product->where('product_name', 'like', '%' . $suggestion . '%')->orWhere('ndc_number', 'like', '%' . $suggestion . '%');
}
```